# Clean the following strings and transform this character vector c into an integer type of vector

Tags: r, string, substring

The string:

```
c1 <- c("cSVgKl9yyb", "e7w4o11oh8", "iYdWYvV7b2", "Epal3cNuGH", "NNhbMR0ocT", "fYaRvoag8B", 
       "LO4fkHm7Kn", "JK8jKhS5De", "DcMAZ7Rxtp", "sV0tqC8XSd")
```

Output must be:

```
[1]     9 74118    72     3     0     8    47    85     7     8
```

Anyone who knows the code to solve this question?

Comment: `gsub('\\D', '', string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)    
str_replace_all(c1, "[^0-9]", "")
[1] "9"     "74118" "72"    "3"     "0"     "8"     "47"    "85"    "7"     "08"
```

Here we remove everything that is *not* contained in the class of digits, where "not" is expressed via `^` and the class of digits is expressed by `0-9`. Alternatively, as suggested by @onyambu, you can use the negative character class for anything that is *not* a digit, `\\D`.

If you want the values to be numeric:

```
as.numeric(str_replace_all(c1, "[^0-9]", ""))
[1]     9 74118    72     3     0     8    47    85     7     8
```